# Using CRM_Utils_Mail and logs

Tags: extension, email, developer

I have a custom extension which I have working great- sends out email using the CRM_Utils_mail function.  The emails go out fine, look fine, but are not registered to the contact's profile (not under the Mailings tab, or any of the others).

```
$emailbody = (CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton()->fetch($turl));
        $params = array();
        $params['from'] = 'Sporting Detection Dogs Association <no@x-x-x.ca>';
        $params['toName'] = $values['Requester_Name'].' '.$values['Requester_lastname'];
        $params['toEmail'] = $contact['email'];
        $params['subject'] = 'Trial Approval';
        $params['text'] = '';
        $params['html'] = $emailbody;
        CRM_Utils_Mail::send($params);
```

Is there a parameter I can add to make it add to the history for the record?  Also, as a sidenote, how do I add more than one toEmail address?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CRM_Activity_BAO_Activity::sendEmail(). An example of its use at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/236007df15c5e3c65866b9cdd53fcd7593bb82c8/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php#L416

Note that it's not an "official" api and may change in the future, but that's also true of CRM_Utils_Mail.